# unrecognized command line option ‘-fstack-protector-strong’ with arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, raspberry-pi3

I have cloned the Raspberry Pi toolchain using the following command and added the tools path to bashrc

```
git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools.git --depth=1
echo PATH=$PATH:~raspberry/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Cloned the raspberry pi kernel sources

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux
```

Simple hello world module

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
static int test_hello_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO"%s: In init\n", __func__);
    return 0;
}

static void test_hello_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO"%s: In exit\n", __func__);
}

module_init(test_hello_init);
module_exit(test_hello_exit);
```

Makefile

```
obj-m := hello.o

all:
    make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- -C /home/jamal/raspberrypi/linux M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- -C /home/jamal/raspberrypi/linux M=$(PWD) clean
```

It's failing with the following error:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fstack-protector-strong’
scripts/Makefile.build:309: recipe for target '/home/jamal/Linux_Device_Drivers/hello.o' failed
```

Previously, this used to work, not sure what has changed and now i am getting this error

Comment: What version of gcc?  (Run `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -v`.)  Has it been upgraded or downgraded recently?

Comment: gcc version 4.8.3 20140303 (prerelease) (crosstool-NG linaro-1.13.1+bzr2650 - Linaro GCC 2014.03). I have not downgraded as i am using prebuilt toolchain

Comment: It looks to me like `-fstack-protector-strong` was not added to gcc until version 4.9.  I wouldn't have thought this would have ever worked with gcc 4.8.3.

Comment: if you have gcc 4.8, you can try with `-fstack-protector-all` instead